# I have nuget restore errors with the latest Artifactory Pro 6.12.2 release

Tags: linux, centos

We were running Artifactory Pro (on-premise) 6.11.3 on CentOS 7.6.1810. After upgrading to 6.12.2 the local nuget repo is broken.

When a nuget client (in this case Visual Studio) tries to restore our internally built nuget packages from the local nuget repo, they get an error message like below:

The feed 'my-nuget-local [https://my-nuget-url/artifactory/api/nuget/my-nuget-local]' lists package 'xyz.1.0.0-build.86' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
Unable to find package 'xyz.1.0.0-build.86'.

In the artifactory.log, it does not show any error message. In the request.log, I see error 404:
20190925173354|45|REQUEST|10.145.82.224|anonymous|GET|/api/nuget/my-nuget-local/Download/xyz/1.0.0-build.86|HTTP/1.0|404|0

The strange thing is if I download the nuget package, i.e. xyz.1.0.0-build.86.nupkg through the Artifactory web gui; delete the package from the repo; and then re-upload the package via the gui to the repo; it fixes the error, i.e. Visual Studio is able to restore the nuget package that it complains about before.

This issue does not happen with Artifactory 6.11.3; only after we upgrade to 6.12.2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to re-install Studio? And your Internet settings for firewall It look that it’s your local issue .Try doing this.